# How do I debug a Pocket PC app running over a wireless network?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, compact-framework, pocketpc

How do I debug an app running on a remote device, Pocket PC 4.2 (2003), over a wireless network (802.11)? I can remote debug with ActiveSync when the device is cradled (57K baud). I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

I am familiar with wireless debugging in Windows Mobile 5.

Comment: You could at least take it up to 115.2K instead of 57.6K.  Go to Active Sync Tools/Options and press the Options button and change the speed.  I never understood why the default was 57K when 115K is faster.

Comment: Thanks for the advice -- options is greyed out connected or not.  I really hate active sync. -- why could they not have just left in 802.11 option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug Pocket PC 2003 over the network from Visual Studio 2008:

- go to Tools/Options to bring up the Options Dialog.
- In the tree select Device Tools/Devices select Pocket PC 2003 in both the Drop Down at the top and the list box in the middle,
- press the Properties button
- uncheck the Detect when device is disconnected

You will need to have the device cradled to begin debugging for the first time.  After Visual Studio has connected to the device, you should be able to remove the device from the cradle.

The other step needed is to enable the wireless or dataconnections while the device is cradled

In ActiveSync if on XP

- go to File/Connection Settings
- check the Allow Wireless connections on device check box

In Windows Mobile Device Center on Vista

- go to the Mobile Device Settings/Connection Settings
- check the Allow Data connections check box

in both cases you will need to re-synchronize your device.

As well, you can no longer use the PPP_PEER machine name.

Comment: It was still not working...however... I feel like a moron: I went back in found out that in visual studio I had two periods in my IP address for the device -- crap!

Thank you for the help - it is working now --

I appriciate you taking the time to verify it on the same device.

I would have assumed that visual studio would not have let me enter a invalid IP -- interesting!

--Joe